# GCC linker failed on MAC OS : Undefined symbols for libsodium

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the libsodium api

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sodium.h>

int main(void){
    if(sodium_init()<0){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of gcc -o test test.c

[Log + Sys. Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcBmm.png)

I've already spent too much time trying to fix this, but I can't find anything to solve the problem. What did I miss here ?

Edit : Added the result of a ls /usr/locale/include

[Include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWFey.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/usage "use -lsodium to link it"

Comment: @KamilCuk This solved the problem, thanks a lot !